# takeWhile to test length of nested lists

Tags: list, haskell, stream, pointfree, tacit-programming

I'm new to Haskell, and trying to do the following:

`takeWhile (length < 3) [[1],[1,2],[1..3],[1..4]]`. But this gives an error which I believe is because `takeWhile` would test `length < 3 [1]` instead of `length [1] < 3`, which is what would work. Do I to make `[[1],[1,2],[1..3],[1..4]]` into a list of lengths and then do a `takeWhile (< 3)` for that list of lengths? Or is there a way to do it by directly testing lengths?

Comment: You want to compose the test "is less than 3" and the "give me the length" function. You can either write `(\ xs -> length xs < 3)` or in point-free style `((< 3) . length)`.

Comment: By the way your intuition about `length < 3 [1]` is correct: that can not work. More precisely, it would be `(length < 3) [1]`. This would first compare the function `length` and the number `3`, which is already wrong. But even if that somehow worked and produced a boolean result for the comparison, then said boolean would be applied to `[1]` as if it were a function, which is again wrong.

Comment: `(length < 3)` --> `((<) length 3)` --> `((<) <$> length <*> pure 3)` and suddenly it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compose `length` and `(< 3)` to achieve what you want:

```
takeWhile ((< 3) . length) [[1],[1,2],[1..3],[1..4]]
```